# Read float pixel data from a file back to C#

Tags: c#, c++, image

In C++, I write a float image into a file:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("image.fft", "wb");

float* pixels = getPixel();

fwrite((unsigned char*)pixels, sizeof(pixels), width*height, fp);
```

For analyzing the image, we need to read the float image into C#. I am stuck with how to read the float image "image.fft" into C#. I know the size width and height of the float image.

Comment: Try using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx

Comment: Do you need the result as an image or are you only interested in the bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this bimap constructor  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx , just use GCHandle to byte array from file to get IntPtr or something like this:

```
 Bitmap BytesToBitmap (byte[] bmpBytes, Size imageSize)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap (imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height);

    BitmapData bData  = bmp.LockBits (new Rectangle (0,0, bmp.Size.Width,bmp.Size.Length),
        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

    // Copy the bytes to the bitmap object
    Marshal.Copy (bmpBytes, 0, bData.Scan0, bmpBytes.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bData);
    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use Bitmap class for get and set pixel
for more information follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx)

Comment: For this line: myBitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, Color.Black); How can I interpret a float pixel to replace: Color.Back?

Comment: use this:Color.FromArgb(greenvalue,redvalue,bluevalue)

Comment: the problem is that if I read the file to byte[]. I dont know what is green, red and blue values?

Comment: instead of this code Color.FromArgb(greenvalue,redvalue,bluevalue) use single value :Color.FromArgb(argdvalue);